# Changepage to page that is dynamically created

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created dynamic page with this code and this works fine:

```
    var b = $('body');
    $('<div data-role="page" id="test" data-theme="b">').appendTo(b).page();
```

After the creation of the page, I want to change the page to this:

```
    $.mobile.changePage('#test", { transition: "none"});
```

The problem is that this isn't working because it cannot find the page that I created before. I think there needs a refresh or something I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following: after appending and before changing the page call `$.mobile.initializePage();`.